# how to encrypt and decrypt with AES.MODE_CBC

Tags: encryption, cryptography

So I been trying to figure out an easy way to encrypt and decrypt simple text with AES.MODE_CBC and I can't seem to find a good tutorial about it. I was hoping someone could help me here. I am able to encrypt the message but when it comes to decrypting I cant seem to find an easy way to do so.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64



def padding(msg):
  return msg + (((16-len(msg) % 16)) * '\x00')


def CBC():
  block_size=16

  # secret key
  key = b'Sixteen byte key'

  # input message
  msg='Attack at dawn'


  # Encrypt
  iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
  encrypt_mode = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
  cipher_text = base64.b64encode(iv + encrypt_mode.encrypt((padding(msg))))
  print cipher_text



  # Decrypt
  cipher_text = base64.b64decode(cipher_text)
  encrypt_mode = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
  plain_text = iv + encrypt_mode.decrypt(cipher_text)
  print plain_text

  CBC()
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove & use instead of prefix the IV during decryption:

```
iv, ciphertext = ciphertext[:AES.block_size], ciphertext[AES.block_size:]
```

Comment: @GregS I would have, but I don't have my Python environment configured correctly (and my python skills leave something to be desired, I'm not using it that much). Thanks for the additional info, I'll presume it runs...

Comment: I'll presume it runs too: I didn't check it :)